# Bibliotecas de suporte do Android devem ser compiladas junto na APK?

Tags: android, apk

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para Android, sendo que ele usa duas bibliotecas que o Google disponibiliza.

A `appcompat-v7` é usada para ter *action bar* em dispositivos com versão 2.3 ou inferior, pois esta só foi adicionada na versão 3, e o `google-play-services` para usar os serviços do Google Analytics.

O ponto é que depois que adicionei estas bibliotecas, o tamanho final do APK pulou de 160Kb para dois 2Mb. Isso aconteceu porque os arquivos dessas duas bibliotecas passaram a ser compilados juntos com o APK.

A minha dúvida é se é assim mesmo que funciona ou se devo configurar algo para que estas bibliotecas não sejam compiladas e sejam encontradas em *runtime.*

Comment: Pelo que sei, tem de ser compiladas mesmo. Até porque precisas delas para a aplicação funcionar. "Encontradas em runtime"? E depois como instalarias o apk num Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elas tem de ser compiladas. A única solução que conheço pra evitar isso é através de extensões ao ambiente de execução do Java, conforme este [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html) explica melhor.

Algo inviável para desenvolvimento Android e um tanto dificultoso mesmo em ambientes desktop, já que você não tem como assegurar que o JRE do usuário conterá as extensões que você criou.